# How do we know the outgoing url of the MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that has a view called Products.

This Products View has a Left Menu Navigation that is implemented using NavMenuProducts.ascx Partial View. This Menu is implemented using JQuery Treeview so that it has the list of ProductNames as the Parent Node and it is expandable(For Example: 10 Products). Each of these Products have a ChildNode as DocTypeName and it is a hyperlink(For Example: 3 DocTypeNames).

When the user clicks ChildNode Hyperlink all the matching Documents are displayed and is implemented using Ajaxy call. So that the user has better UI experience and the display URL is always http://DocShare .

Now based on the link that the user clicked, how can i know the outgoing url? (For Example: Though it is displaying http://DocShare, the url could be  http://DocShare/Products/Product1/Letter

Appreciate your responses.

Thanks

Comment: can you show me some script to explain how you implement the ajax call?

Comment: As a note, doing everything over AJAX while always keeping the URL the same is _not_ a better UI experience. This breaks both bookmarking and the back button. If you don't want to do full requests and page re-renders, take a look at one of the many jquery history plugins.

Comment: It is not clear what the question is. So what is the question? The URL is decided by the controller and action and its parameters and you have to write the same URL in the view while rendering, so what is the problem?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590863/can-we-dynamically-change-the-url-with-ajaxy-call-on-asp-net-mvc-page

Answer (score 0):

On Facebook and Twitter, content loaded asynchronously modifies the current page URL by adding the permanent link for the loaded content as a value in URL's anchor/hash. For example: http://www.website.com/#!path/to/some/content

jQuery BBQ is an excellent plugin for creating a navigatable history of client-side actions by updating the current URL as events occur. jQuery BBQ can respond to changes to the current page hash so that specific items/values within the hash can be parsed and then used to initiate client-side requests for the desired content.

[jQuery BBQ Plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/)